# How to throw an exception using lambda expression

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8

I need to throw an exception if array contains a negative number.

What is best practices to do that using java8 features ?

```
Integer array = {11, -10, -20, -30, 10, 20, 30};

array.stream().filter(i -> i < 0) // then throw an exception
```

Comment: you should not throw an exception in a stream processing, that's an anti-pattern

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Thanks for the information. Have you got a source for that or a place to read more, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which return a boolean then if true thrown an exception like this:

```
boolean containsNegativeNumber = array.stream().anyMatch(i -> i < 0);
if (containsNegativeNumber) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List contains negative numbers.");
}
```

Or directly as this:

```
if (array.stream().anyMatch(i -> i < 0)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List contains negative numbers.");
}
```

Comment: I think the second approach is great because you don't use any variable to throw the exception